# Sort ListBox in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listitem

I have some code at my job that uses ASP.net (which I have never touched) but I need to sort it.  Here is the ListBox that I need to sort by Dscrp:

```
    foreach (InteractiveInfo template in ddlsource)
    {
        Product thisProduct = FindProduct(template.UProductId);
        if (thisProduct != null)
        {
            ddlProducts.Items.Add(
                new ListItem(
                    string.Format("{0} ({1})", thisProduct.Dscrp, thisProduct.UProductId),
                    template.UProductId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
        }
    }
    ddlProducts.DataBind();
}
```

I found this link:

https://gist.github.com/chartek/1655779

so I tried adding this at the end:

```
ddlProducts.Items.Sort();
```

but it just gives me this error:

> Does not contain a definition for 'Sort'

Comment: Are you sure this is asp-classic? Both that `.DataBind()` and your C# tag make me doubt it.

Comment: @Martha not 100% sure but it is not MVC.  It uses the aspx extension and the aspx.cs for the code behind files so I thought it was legacy.

Comment: No, .aspx is the extension for asp.net. Classic asp just uses .asp extensions (and has no concept of "code behind").

Comment: @Martha, thank you.  I fixed the OP.  Do you have any idea how to perform this? I tried a few other things but nothing is working.

Comment: Sorry, no: I don't do languages with curly braces unless forced to at gunpoint. :/  (You probably should fix your tags while you're editing.)

Comment: @Martha thank you done

Answer (score 1):

If your application is on .NET 3.5 or above, take a look at [MSDN: Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb383977.aspx).

The [tutorial link](https://gist.github.com/chartek/1655779) you provided is making use of the extension method concept where `Sort()` method is decorated onto `ListItemCollection` (i.e. `ddlProducts.Items`) type.

The extension methods should be defined inside non-generic static class. So the tutorial missing a class definition. You can try with:

```
public static class ExtensionsMethods //Notice the static class
{
   public static void Sort(this ListItemCollection items)
   {
          //... Implement rest of logic from the tutorial
   }

   // Other extension methods, if required.
}
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this its not perfect but update it as per your requirement

```
    public static void Sort(this ListItemCollection items)
    {
        var itemsArray = new ListItem[items.Count];
        items.CopyTo(itemsArray,0);

        Array.Sort(itemsArray, (x, y) => (string.Compare(x.Value, y.Value, StringComparison.Ordinal)));
        items.Clear();
        items.AddRange(itemsArray);

    }
```

Comment: Apart from it doesn't work. You have sorted by `x.Value` and `y.Value` rather than `x.Text` and `y.Text`, meaning it is sorting on the underlying ids (`thisProduct.UProductId`) rather than the displayed `thisProduct.Dscrp`, so appears to behave erratically to the user.